# Android - ParseObject Id is Null

Tags: android, parse-platform, objectid

Could anyone please help me with this issue. I have 2 activities for user to register their profile. I created a ParseObject user then pass this user object to the second activity. I used user.getObjectId() to get the ID of user object, but the ID is always null. I wonder if anyone could help me find the ParseObject's user ID. Please see my code below. Thank you

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

protected EditText mFirstName;
protected EditText mMiddleName;
protected EditText mLastName;
protected EditText mUserEmail;
protected EditText mPhoneNumber;
protected EditText mAddressLine1;
protected EditText mAddressLine2;
protected EditText mEmergencyName;
protected EditText mEmergencyPhone;
protected EditText mEmergencyRelationship;
protected EditText mEmergencyOtherInfo;
protected Button mNextPageButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    //Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    //Initialize
    mFirstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNameRegisterEditText);
    mMiddleName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.middleNameRegisterEditText);
    mLastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastNameRegisterEditText);
    mUserEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailRegisterEditText);
    mPhoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneRegisterEditText);
    mAddressLine1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addressRegisterText);
    mAddressLine2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address2RegisterText);
    mEmergencyName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emergencyNameEditText);
    mEmergencyPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emergencyPhoneEditText);
    mEmergencyRelationship = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emergencyRelationshipEditText);
    mEmergencyOtherInfo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medicalInfoEditText);
    mNextPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextPageButton);

    //Listen to register button click
    mNextPageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Get first name, middle name, last name, user email, phone number, address line 1, address line 2,
            //emergency name, emergency phone, emergency relationship, emergency other info and convert them to string
            String firstName = mFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
            String middleName = mMiddleName.getText().toString().trim();
            String lastName = mLastName.getText().toString().trim();
            String userEmail = mUserEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String phoneNumber = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
            String addressLine1 = mAddressLine1.getText().toString().trim();
            String addressLine2 = mAddressLine2.getText().toString().trim();
            String emergencyName = mEmergencyName.getText().toString().trim();
            String emergencyPhone = mEmergencyPhone.getText().toString().trim();
            String emergencyRelationship = mEmergencyRelationship.getText().toString().trim();
            String emergencyOtherInfo = mEmergencyOtherInfo.getText().toString().trim();

            //String password = mUserPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            ParseObject user = new ParseObject("User");

            //Store user in parse
            user.put("firstName", firstName);
            user.put("middleName", middleName);
            user.put("lastName", lastName);
            user.put("email", userEmail);
            user.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            user.put("addressLine1", addressLine1);
            user.put("addressLine2", addressLine2);
            user.put("emergencyName", emergencyName);
            user.put("emergencyPhone", emergencyPhone);
            user.put("emergencyRelationship", emergencyRelationship);
            user.put("otherInfo", emergencyOtherInfo);
            user.put("username", userEmail);

            user.saveInBackground();

            //Passing user object to AppearanceActivity and take user to appearance register page
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, AppearanceActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("user_id", user.getObjectId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String firstName = mFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
        String middleName = mMiddleName.getText().toString().trim();
        String lastName = mLastName.getText().toString().trim();
        String userEmail = mUserEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String phoneNumber = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
        String addressLine1 = mAddressLine1.getText().toString().trim();
        String addressLine2 = mAddressLine2.getText().toString().trim();
        String emergencyName = mEmergencyName.getText().toString().trim();
        String emergencyPhone = mEmergencyPhone.getText().toString().trim();
        String emergencyRelationship = mEmergencyRelationship.getText().toString().trim();
        String emergencyOtherInfo = mEmergencyOtherInfo.getText().toString().trim();

        //String password = mUserPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        final ParseObject user = new ParseObject("User");

        //Store user in parse
        user.put("firstName", firstName);
        user.put("middleName", middleName);
        user.put("lastName", lastName);
        user.put("email", userEmail);
        user.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        user.put("addressLine1", addressLine1);
        user.put("addressLine2", addressLine2);
        user.put("emergencyName", emergencyName);
        user.put("emergencyPhone", emergencyPhone);
        user.put("emergencyRelationship", emergencyRelationship);
        user.put("otherInfo", emergencyOtherInfo);
        user.put("username", userEmail);

        user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Saved successfully.
                    //Passing user object to AppearanceActivity and take user to appearance register page
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, AppearanceActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("user_id", user.getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    // The save failed.
                    Log.d("", "User update error: " + e);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if this will fix your problem, but I think you need to use `ParseUser` to work with users, not `ParseObject`.

Answer (score 0):

First some general remarks when working with Parse :

`Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");`

Should happen in the OnCreate hook of your `Application` not an `Activity` instance.

ParseObject#saveInBackground is asynchronous. Thus it renders waiting for the objectId to update useless.
You can provide a Callback function to your save call which will be called when the saving has finished!

**Nonetheless** I am pretty sure you want to **Register** a user (since the Name of the RegisterActivity indicates that), so why don't you simply use this example :

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("my name");
user.setPassword("my pass");
user.setEmail("email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
      // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
      // to figure out what went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

Please also make sure to read [the official docs](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-signup) before getting to code something which may already have been taken care off.
Especially for your use case you might find [this](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui) useful !

Comment: Thanks @throws_exceptions_at_you. I like your nick name :) I read the official docs but my app has different design. Instead of using just 1 activity to register user, my app has 3 activities for user to fill in their profile information before sending data to Parse. This would requires me to pass user object between different activities.

Comment: Thanks. You should use Fragments wherever you can. This will take care of your problem.